# How to extract only a specific sublayer from pcap?

Tags: linux, wireshark, pcap, tshark

How to extract only a specific sublayer from a pcap file? For example all packets contain these layers: `Ethernet`, `IP`, `SCTP`, ... I need to extract the hex code of packets from the `SCTP` layer on. I could extract the packets with `tshark`, using the following command:

```
tshark -x -r mylog.pcap
```

But the output hex packets contain all layers including `Ethernet` and `IP`. How can I exclude the `Ethernet` and `IP` layers in the extracted output?

Comment: Can I suggest taking a look at scapy http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/ it allows you a lot of power in this sort of case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [python](http://python.org) + [scapy](http://secdev.org/projects/scapy) to select a given layer in each packet with `p.getlayer(SCTP)` or any other layer.

The contents of your pcap file can be [read](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#index-9) using:

```python
capture=rdpcap("/path/to/mylog.pcap")
```

the processed with something like

```python
for pkt in capture:
   print pkt.getlayer(SCTP)
```

#### open a file :

```python
>>> a=rdpcap("/spare/captures/isakmp.cap")
>>> a
<isakmp.cap: UDP:721 TCP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>
```

Check http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#index-9

Comment: How can I open the file with scapy?

Comment: I get the following error when trying to open the file: `Scapy_Exception: Not a pcap capture file (bad magic)`. The file is fine and I can open it in wireshark though.

Comment: That suggests that the file is not an expected format.

Comment: Just tried with the sample file at http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol_.28SCTP.29 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: The file is probably a pcap-ng file rather than a pcap file.  If scapy is using libpcap to read the file, then it's probably using a version of libpcap earlier than 1.1 (which can read some pcap-ng files); if it's running on Windows and using WinPcap, WinPcap is based on a pre-1.1 libpcap and can't read pcap-ng files; if it's using its own code to read files, that code needs to be enhanced to read pcap-ng files.

Comment: You could use editcap to convert pcap-ng files to pcap files - `editcap -F libpcap` {*pcap-ng file*} {*pcap file to write*}